# Creating/Nesting matrix

Tags: r, matrix, unique

I have the following matrix:

[image: matrix]

I want to create 2 new matrix for the companies! with the company code as distribution key.

Comment: Don't post pictures of data. See [how to create a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). It's best to give the explicit desired output for the sample input.

Answer (score 0):

Like @MrFlick said, no pictures of data; rather use a minimal example like this:

```
df <- data.frame(Company = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2), v1 = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2), v2 = c(2, 2, 4, 2, 2, 1), v3 = c(1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1))
```

To come back to your problem, `subset`is perfectly suited for this:

```
comp1 <- subset(df, Company == 1)
comp2 <- subset(df, Company == 2)
```

Comment: Thank you guys! You are awesome !

Now the trick is that I have 206 stocks with daily stock prices, outstanding debt and the risk free rate (for up to 25 years). All in a big dataframe/matrix (total observations of 650.000)  

So, i want to apply some calculations / functions to every 206 dataframe/matrix. (I have all the functions coded)

Can you help me out? maybe with a for loop or apply function?